# Specifying "all" type using Python type-hints

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I annotate a variable in Python as being able to possess **either** of two types, I can use `typing.Union`, as per this question:

> [How to specify multiple return types using type-hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints)

However, how do I go about annotating a variable as having to possess **both** of two types?

**Use case**

This is a bit contrived since, for this small example, we could just define a `TwoCourseMenu` class. However if we have *n* interfaces then we really don't want to have to define *n*×*n* combinations.

I want to replace `Union` (*any of*) with something that means *all of*.

```
from typing import Union

class BasicMeal:
    def main_name( self ):
        return "spam"

class IWithDesert:
    def desert_name( self ):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class TwoCourseSpamMenu( BasicMeal, IWithDesert ):
    def desert_name( self ):
        return "spam"

def present( input: Union[BasicMeal, IWithDesert] ):
    print( f"You're having '{input.main_name()}' followed by '{input.desert_name()}'." )

present( TwoCourseSpamMenu() )
```

Comment: As of now, [still not possible](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213). There's probably a good dupe target around here somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mypy: how to verify a type has multiple super classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319112/mypy-how-to-verify-a-type-has-multiple-super-classes)

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks, I'm using PyCharm and not MyPy, but it seems `typing` is built *for* MyPy, and not the other way around [see here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213), so I guess this is a duplicate!