# Python typing multiple inheritance as parameter

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mypy, python-typing

I want to explicitly type a function parameter, that needs to inherit from two classes.
Example:

```py
class SomeInterface:
    def first_function():
        pass

class SuperClass:
    def other_function():
        # implementation here
    # more function definitions

class C(A, B):
    # overrides first_function

def my_typed_function(param: Union[A,B]):
    param.first_function() # mypy: variant B does not have that function
    param.other_function() # mypy: variant A does not have that function
```

What can I use instead of `Union` to show that relationship? (Keep in mind that there can also be other implementations like C passed to this, so I cannot explicitly use C)

I also looked into [typing protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) and defined A as a Protocol, but running into the same problem since B is an actual class and cannot be combined into the protocol.

Comment: Isn't this what `C` is for? `def my_typed_function(param: C):` If you can have multiple implementations, maybe they should be subclasses of `C`.

Comment: There might also be a D implementing both things, and I dont necessarily have control over that. This is why I want to be generic

Comment: You probably just want to define a protocol that supports `first_function` and `other_function`, without any reference to `SomeInterface` or `SuperClass`.

Comment: Related? [how to verify a type has multiple super classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50319112/3890632)

Comment: Can probably be done but is a bit ugly since I want to use a lot of functions of SuperClass and that feels extremely redundant

Comment: So if I get this right, you want to say "any class that extends A and B" while union gives you "a class that extends either A or B"?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. And B does not *need* to be a class, but could also be and ABC, Protocol, etc
"Any class that extends A and also has functionality of B" would put it on the point

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining an intermediate abstract class:

```
class MyMixedType(A,B):
    pass

class C(MyMixedType):
    # very specific implementation

def my_typed_function(param: MyMixedType):
    ...
```

**BUT** this only works since I can have all classes implement `MyMixedType` and thus offloading the multiple inheritance to one level above.

Related: [how to verify a type has multiple super classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50319112/3890632) (thanks @khelwood)
After looking into the question and numerous linked github issues, this seems to be an ongoing issue since ~2018. A solution would be called `Intersection` but is to the best of my knowledge still not implemented. PyCharm/IntelliJ seem to support it though with their in-editor type checking.