# How to typehint that an object of a class is also adhering to a Protocol in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a set of classes, Lets call them `Foo` and `Bar`, where both inherit from a base class `Father` that is defined outside of the current scope (not by me). I have definied a protocol class `DummyProtocol` that has a function `do_something`.

```
class DummyProtocol(Protocol):
   def do_something(self):
      ...
   

class Foo(Father):
   def do_something(self):
      pass

class Bar(Father):
   def do_something(self):
      pass
```

I have a function `create_instance`.

```
def create_dummy_and_father_instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to typehint it in a way, that cls is typehinted to accept a class that is of type `Father` that also implements the `DummyProtocol`.

So I changed the function to this to indicate that cls is a type that inherit from both `Father` and `DummyProtocol`

```
def create_dummy_and_father_instance(
    cls: Type[tuple[Father, DummyProtocol]], *args, **kwargs
):
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I get this error in `mypy`:

```
Cannot instantiate type "Type[Tuple[Father, DummyProtocol]]"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62661785/14617085 is this kind of what you are looking for ??

Comment: @basicmojo I don't think so. I need a typehint that indicates an object is implementing arbitrary numbers of protocols alongside a baseclass in the arguments section. Is changing the class definition my only way?

Comment: ask here, https://discord.gg/t4gsyP9EQ3, the admin, asotille, is really good at typehinting stuff

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue and found [this discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) on proposed `Intersection` types which seem to be exactly what is needed (e.g. see [this comment](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213#issuecomment-984556481)).

Unfortunately this feature is not yet supported by the Python typing system, but there's a PEP in the making.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a second Father class which inherits from Father and Protocol (see also [mypy: how to verify a type has multiple super classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319112/mypy-how-to-verify-a-type-has-multiple-super-classes)):

```
class DummyProtocol(Protocol):

    def do_something(self):
        ...
    
class Father:
    pass
    
class Father2(Father, DummyProtocol):
    pass
    
class Foo(Father2):

    def do_something(self):
        pass
    
class Bar(Father2):

    def do_something(self):
        pass
    
class FooNot(Father):
    pass
    
def create_dummy_and_father_instance(
    cls: Type[Father2]
):
    return cls()
    
create_dummy_and_father_instance(Foo)
create_dummy_and_father_instance(Bar)
create_dummy_and_father_instance(FooNot)  # mypy error ok
```

Comment: But isn't this against the usage of Protocol? Protocol is only about statice type hinting, not run time influence, isn't it?

Comment: I think not. From the doc: "Note that inheriting from an existing protocol does not automatically turn the subclass into a protocol – it just creates a regular (non-protocol) class or ABC that implements the given protocol (or protocols). The Protocol base class must always be explicitly present if you are defining a protocol."

Comment: so any time I need to make sure something has implemented a base class and a protocol I have to derive a subclass? This is really not optimal.

Comment: No problem with instance, but with class Protocol has some limits.